# Old commit makes git unable to push

Tags: git, github, size, push

I tried to push a file which was above 100 mb and I got the error that you cannot push files that are above 100 mb in size. Then I changed in my file so that the size is now 15 mb, and recommited everything. The problem is that the old commit still exists, and when I try to push everything the old commit "blocks" the new one from pushing. I still get the same error as before with the size limit.

So, my question is whether there is any possibility to make git ignore this commit when pushing or can I remove it from the branch history?

Comment: Do you know which commit# is it ?

Comment: I am using SourceTree, so I know that it is the third commit from the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reset your repository to the commit right before the big 100 mb commit with (this will drop all commits after that hash)

```
git reset --hard <sha1-commit-id>
```

Then recommit your 15 mb file.

Or you can do a interactive rebase and drop the commit (d) which keeps the other commits and reapply them

```
git rebase -i HEAD~N
```

while N is the number of commits you want to go backwards during rebase

Comment: Will I keep my current files then?

Comment: if you do rebase (second suggestion) yes, it will only drop the commit you selected and the reapply all the other commits

Comment: I tried doing the rebase thing but it didn't do as I wanted it to. But your first alternative worked. I have to create a backup on the disk before I used the reset command though. Thank you!